# Must Facebook GraphRequest.Start() be called from main thread?

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin, async-await, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to follow the Getting Started example provided here: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookios

The following GraphRequest works fine when executed within the main thread:

```
var request = new GraphRequest ("/me?fields=name", null, AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString, null, "GET");
request.Start ((connection, result, error) => {
    // Handle if something went wrong with the request
    if (error != null) {
        new UIAlertView ("Error...", error.Description, null, "Ok", null).Show ();
        return;
    }

    // Get your profile name
    var userInfo = result as NSDictionary;
    nameLabel.Text = userInfo ["name"].ToString ();
});
```

However when I run the exact same code from a background thread using *Task.Run*, it seems that the completion handler delegate within *request.Start* is never called.

Does GraphRequest only supports to be executed from the main thread?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
var graphRequest = new GraphRequest ("/me?fields=name,gender", null, AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString, null, "GET");
    var requestConnection = new GraphRequestConnection();
    requestConnection.AddRequest(graphRequest, (connection, result, error) =>
      {
        var profile = result;
      });
    requestConnection.Start();
```